# I can not set up the instance on Google Cloud Platform | Can not type the password

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just physically not able to enter the password for some reason.

```
Allowlisting your IP for incoming connection for 5 minutes...done.
Connecting to database with SQL user [root].Enter password:
```

After this Lines, it asked me to enter a password.

```
mysql --host=$MYSQLIP --user=root \
      --password --verbose < create_table.sql
```

[image]

I push buttons on the keyboard and nothing. It is the first time I see something Cloud related, so I am not sure.

Comment: Your question lacks details. `Cannot type the password` could mean you cannot enter characters, or you entered the password and the password was rejected. It looks like you are using the CLI `gcloud`. Show the command that you are using. Include the error that is reported. What version of the CLI are you using?

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Are you using Cloud SQL? Compute ENgine? Can you detail your path to end there?

Comment: I cannot enter the password. I push button on keyboard and nothing happens.
I am doing a "Ingesting Data Into The Cloud Using Google Cloud Functions
" course on Quiklabs. It involves SQL.

Comment: I am not sure about the version, but yes, it involves gcloud. I added an image to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure it out. The password is invisible. So, you just have to print it blindly and press enter.